# jedi:complete produces a deferred error when using the theano library

Tags: emacs, theano, jedi

In emacs, I am trying to get `jedi:complete` to work with `theano`. To do so, I have the following minimal bit of code.

```
from theano import shared
state = shared(0)

state.#
```

When I place my cursor at the `#` sign, and run `m-x jedi:complete`, I am met with the following error, and no autocompletion is offered.

```
deferred error : (error "\"TypeError(\\\"unhashable type: 'list'\\\",)\"")
```

I wonder if this is an incompatability with a source file in `theano` and `jedi`. But I am not sure, and I do not know what to do to further resolve the issue.

I get a similar error when I try to use `company-jedi`.

I have installed all of my packages through the `packages-list-packages` command, and they are updated with the latest versions.

Comment: Via pip, I updated jedi from 0.8.0-final to 0.9.0, and that changed the error to `deferred error : (error "\"AttributeError(\\\"'Script' object has no attribute 'complete'\\\",)\"")`

Comment: Do you use latest emacs-jedi(jedi-core) ? I fixed deprecated interfaces issue at https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/pull/230 . So I think you cannot get such error with latest emacs-jedi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by looking through `m-x packages-list-packages` and seeing that there was (for some reason) an old deprecated version of jedi installed alongside another version of jedi. I deleted all the deprecated installations I had, and the error has gone away, but `jedi` doesnt seem to be able to autocomplete the above code still. It now just says `No completion found`.